# Attribute a static public ip for a pod in kubernetes

Tags: postfix, docker, nat, cluster, kubernetes

In my data center, I implemented a Kubernetes infrastructure with 3 workers and one master node.

I'm looking to build 5 pods running `postfix mail server`, but
because of risking to be blacklisted, I'm looking to assign a specific public IP to each pod for the outbound traffic.

I don't know if it's possible to do that and is there any solution to `NAT` the pod addresses?

Comment: Hello. Could you tell more about your setup? Which `CNI` are you using? Have you seen [Multus](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni) by any chance?

Comment: Thanks , i'm using weaves for networking .. and the cluster is running on my own datacenter not with cloud provider .. for that reason i jave more work to do

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer as more of a potential pointers to check as there could be specific requirements and limitations of each solution and each infrastructure.

Feel free to expand it.

Possible solutions:

- `Multus` CNI
- `OVS` CNI

---

#### `Multus` CNI

As I said in the comment, one of the possible solutions is `Multus`:

> Multus CNI is a container network interface (CNI) **plugin for Kubernetes that enables attaching multiple network interfaces to pods**. Typically, in Kubernetes each pod only has one network interface (apart from a loopback) -- with Multus you can create a multi-homed pod that has multiple interfaces. This is accomplished by Multus acting as a "meta-plugin", a CNI plugin that can call multiple other CNI plugins.
>
> -- *[Github.com: Intel: Multus CNI](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni)*

Please refer to it's documentation about the configuration and usage:

- *[Github.com: Intel: Multus CNI: Doc: How to use](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni/blob/master/doc/how-to-use.md)*
- *[Github.com: Intel: Multus CNI: Doc: Configuration](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni/blob/master/doc/configuration.md)*

> **A side note!**
>
> Installation of `Multus` could be also specified in Kubernetes provisioning tools like [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/multus.md).

---

#### `OVS` CNI

You can read on official Open vSwitch Github page:

> This plugin allows user to define Kubernetes networks on top of Open vSwitch bridges available on nodes. Note that ovs-cni does not configure bridges, it's up to a user to create them and connect them to L2, L3 or an overlay network.
>
> *[Github.com: Kubevirt: OVS CNI](https://github.com/kubevirt/ovs-cni)*

In the link above there are requirements that need to be met as well some examples.

---

I encourage you to check the additional resources like:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/)*

> **A second side note!**
>
> You can also check if the [Istio Egress gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/) would suit your needs.